# angular 7 HTTP request dynamic form not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

Reactive Form angular 7 creating a dynamic form builder same like link working fine in using JSON in .ts but not working JSON get from HTTP request.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wn34ld  but the JSON response I get from the server

```
{
    "Description": "Transformer Mapping",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "//Document",
            "options": [
                "InstructingAgentMmbId",
                "InstructingAgentName"
            ],
            "type": "select",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "//DocumentLC",
            "label": "List",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "value": "false"
        }
 ],
    "rescode": "0000",
    "status": "Success",
    "timestamp": "2019-06-18 20:06:44.168"
}
```

so based on the response I change Interface model and HTTP service but show error

> FormGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in

```
regConfig:FieldConfig[];
export interface test {
  data?: FieldConfig[];

}
this.http.post<test>('http://155.54.54.45:8080/Auto/transform/mapping', request).subscribe(res => {

  this.regConfig =res.data;
  console.log(this.regConfig)
});
```

Comment: I have no errors

Comment: Provide your html code so we can easily find

Comment: No error in using JSON in ts working fine but using http service not working

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wn34ld